# Will SQL Server 2012 install + run Windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I can't seem to find any information but can I install SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition on a server running Windows Server 2003 R2 x64?

I don't intend to use this for production just for testing and I am unable to rebuild the OS at the moment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. According to the well hidden and difficult to follow documentation on MSDN ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx)) it requires Windows 2008 / Windows Vista or later.

Comment: @Seph glad I could help. I can't believe how difficult it was to find that info, I honestly don't think it's linked to from the Microsoft.com/SQLServer pages at all. Their new website design is another triumph of style over substance.